# Is it appropriate to use Likert-scale answers in ANCOVA then only comparing the extreme values?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, likert, ancova

Stats are not my strong point, but my understanding of ANOVA/ANCOVA is that it's used primarily for experimental design where the IV needs to be a categorical variable, and with a continuous variable as the DV to compare means between different manipulations/conditions.

However, [this research article](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Student+perceptions+and+achievement+in+a+university+blended+learning+strategic+initiative&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi56N-QtK_PAhXHLo8KHWVsAfEQgQMIHDAA) about blended learning effectiveness seems to put the responses to a 5-point likert-scale (eg 'I am satisfied with this [blended course]: strongly disagree ~ strongly agree') as the IV, and 'student grade' as the DV to compare means (pp3-4) using SPSS. The conclusion argued that students who are most satisfied (rated 5) have significantly higher grades than those who are least satisfied (rated 1) (p.4, table 1). I found this puzzling and have a couple of questions..

1. How is this analysis done in SPSS? Did they put the Likert responses as the IV and then do post-hoc analysis/planned contrast to compare 'strongly disagree' condition to 'strongly agree' condition?
2. Is it the appropriate analysis to do? Wouldn't a regression to find which questionnaire item best predict grades be a more appropriate tool to use?
3. I know next to nothing about Structural Equation Modelling, but shouldn't an even more proper analysis technique for this kind of data be SEM? As I understand it, first, they should have done EFA/CFA to confirm that all questionnaire items load into their supposed constructs, then do an SEM to find which construct best predict student grades?
4. My question seems related to [this related question here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105681/likert-item-as-independent-variable-for-anova) which suggest that ANOVA is *not* the right way to go about it? And yet, this particular article got published at a [rather well-regarded publication](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/the-internet-and-higher-education/) in my field... So, does it indicate a flaw during the peer review process, or am I missing something about the analysis?

(PS: the article is free to view from where I am currently, apologies if the article is paywalled for you. Please suggest what I should do if this is indeed the case)